# VirtualBox nat network not starting

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

I have Virtualbox 4.3.36 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I am
Trying to make a NAT network work, but I can not start it using `VBoxManage`, I get this message:

```
VBoxManage natnetwork start --netname NatNetwork
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) - Operation failed (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "Start(Bstr("whatever").raw())" at line 449 of file VBoxManageNATNetwork.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Failed to start network
```

If I start a virtual OS, this one gets a correct IP & gateway from the DHCP server on the NAT network, but it can not ping the gateway, nor the DHCP server, nor the outside world.

I tried several NIC types, but the outcome is always the same. Tried creating/starting the NAT network both with `vBoxManage` as well as the GUI, but with the same results.

There is no problem if I set the network type to NAT, but I would like to have some virtual machines to be able to communicate to each other & the outside world.